# Calculate Average time spent closing a project

Tags: powerbi, dax

Current have the following measure that sums up total time spent closing a project type (Template). Basically, sums up Time Spent on a unique Project ID (templateID) that has a Close Date and groups them by project type for each Employee. I then have a table visual that lists Employees, Project Type (Template), and Team's avg close time for each project type (Template). I now need a measure that calculates an employees avg closing time for each template so I can add it to the table visual and compare them to the team avg closing time. The measure below initially had AVERAGEA at the beginning but was just calculating the sum and ignoring the average part.

```
Time_Spent average per Template_ID = 
    CALCULATE(SUM('Activities'[Time_Spent]), FILTER(Activities, Activities[Close_Date] <> BLANK()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might look something similar to:

```
=
  AVERAGEX(
    VALUES(Project[Template Id]),
    CALCULATE(
      SUM('Activities'[Time_Spent]),
      Activities[Close_Date] <> BLANK()
    )
  )
```